# How to build a sequence from an external non-suspending function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I've got a java method `visitChildrenRecursively(Node root, NodeVisitor p)` that allows me to iterate over elements of a tree-like structure by providing a SAM visitor.

I'd like to convert this approach to a Sequence-based iteration.

However, this code...

```
buildSequence {
    visitChildrenRecursively(root, NodeVisitor {
        yield(it)
    })
}
```

...fails compilation with error `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body` at line `yield(it)`

The Kotlin coroutines [Informal description](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md#wrapping-callbacks) suggests my `visitChildrenRecursively` could be converted to a suspending function by wrapping it inside a `suspendCoroutine` block.

Would that be the correct approach, or is this even possible without resorting to a `produce` approach from `kotlinx` as shown in [the kotlinx coroutines guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#building-channel-producers) ?

I also tried section "Asynchronous sequences" in the Informal description, with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're asking for the impossible. Kotlin doesn't implement coroutines through some backdoor JVM magic, but through the transformation of regular Java methods. Suspendable functions involve a hidden method signature change and their return type changes as well. Where your `Visitor` may have a method

```
void visit(Node)
```

this would have to become

```
Object visit(Node, Continuation)
```

Even if we pretend this is possible, your next barrier would be `visitChildrenRecursively()` which has no knowledge of the special contract for suspendable functions. They require the caller to pass in its continuation for a normal call and their own continuation for a resuming call. They return `COROUTINE_SUSPENDED` when suspended, and the caller must return the same value itself if it gets it.

If you can copy-paste the implementation of `visitChildrenRecursively()` and migrate it to Kotlin, then you might have a chance to succeed.